# "tput: Unknown terminal 'emacs'" messages when using PyCharm / iPython console on Windows

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm, anaconda

I am using PyCharm with iPython on Windows.  The only Python I have installed on the box is the latest Anaconda distribution, Python 3.4 flavor.

Very often, while using the console, I get numerous instances of the following warning message:

```
tput: unknown terminal "emacs"
```

This is mixed in with the normal output.  Has anyone else experienced and/or fixed this?  I have dug through both the iPython and PyCharm documentation and have not found anything related.

Comment: I didn't even know tput existed on Windows. Is this the terminal inside Pycharm? You could try asking on a pycharm support forum, but I'm not really sure which piece would be responsible for that.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that Cygwin is installed and for awhile I had it listed as the terminal under Settings -> Tools -> Terminal.  I cleared that out once I started seeing these messages.  Maybe the setting is still stuck somewhere?

Comment: That sounds like it could be related - tput is generally a Unix thing, as far as I know. Could Cygwin still be on $PATH?

Comment: I'm running PyCharm 5.0.4 with IPython 3.5.1 via Anaconda3. I get the same tput: unknown terminal "emacs" message after every print statement that uses sys.stdout.flush().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install anything new recently?

Check your path for anything "unixy", for example I removed ...\Git\bin from my path and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: For me removing `C:\cygwin64\bin` from the `PATH` fixed the problem.

Comment: Clearing xming bin directory from my path worked for me