# pandas printing `tput: unknown terminal "emacs"`

Tags: python, shell, pandas, emacs, ipython

I'm using `pandas` installed via Anaconda on Windows 10.

I run an IPython terminal inside an emacs inferior Python shell.

Every time I print a `pandas.DataFrame` to the terminal, I get an error message `tput: unknown terminal "emacs"`.

The error message is then followed by the correct output so I wish I could just turn off the error message.

It seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537994/tput-unknown-terminal-emacs-messages-when-using-pycharm-ipython-console-o).  For what it's worth, I do have Git/bin on my PATH environment variable but I don't know how this would affect anything.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of python and pandas are using ? Try using pip install --upgrade pandas, and see that fix issue

Comment: python version 3.5.1. I was using pandas version 0.17.1. Now upgraded to 0.18.0 and still get the tput message.

Comment: joblib package caused me to have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem while manipulating `pandas.DataFrame` in the debug perspective of Eclipse (Mars 2) under Windows 7.

When trying to examine the content of the `DataFrame` the console would output :

```
tput: unknown terminal "emacs"
```

while the value would display `(pending)`, and the debug session would freeze forever.

I identified that the `tput` command was indeed a unix command shipped in by cygwing :

```
D:\smouton>where tput
d:\smouton\cygwin64\bin\tput.exe
```

The workaround I set up is to modify the `PATH` variable before launching Eclipse. This is conveniently done by launching the following batch file instead of Eclipse executable :

```
REM Remove reference to "unixy" stuff before calling eclipse
REM This avoids 'tput: unknown terminal "emacs"' error when manipulating pandas dataframe
SET PATH=%PATH:;C:\MinGW\bin;d:\smouton\cygwin64\bin;=;%
REM launch eclipse
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe"
```

This file simply removes `C:\MinGW\bin` and `d:\smouton\cygwin64\bin` from PATH, then starts eclipse.

I suppose a similar workaround can solve the OP's issue with IPython as well.

Answer (score 1):

The fix that "jurasource" suggested was to inspect the `PATH` to see if there are any elements of the path that would not be recognized by windows but would instead be recognized by a unix-like operating system. That is why `/git/bin` would be an issues, that path is recognizable by a unix-like operating system but not windows.

Comment: I know, if this had been on the emacs stack exchange I would have written it as a comment but here I am 21 points short of being allowed to comment. I wanted to do my best to contribute and help, and I thought that that was more important than where the comment was. I will delete it if is deemed inappropriate

Comment: I have /git/bin on the path because I need the unix-style find and grep for emacs to use.  Is there any way that I can get rid of the tput message without breaking find and grep for emacs?

Answer (score 0):

set environment variable TERM=xterm,  then restart pycharm's python console can solve this problem.

to do this, first try this in cmd.exe:

tput -T xterm # see if xterm is accepted. if not, try another one.